# Can the time zone affect a java.util.Date.compareTo() result?

Tags: java, date, ftp

I have a program that stores a local copy of a file hosted in an FTP server. The program automatically checks every day if the file has been updated on the server using the following code:

```
FTPFile remoteFile = ftpClient.mlistFile(remotePath);
Date remoteDate = remoteFile.getTimestamp().getTime();
BasicFileAttributes localFile = Files.readAttributes(Paths.get(localPath), BasicFileAttributes.class);
Date localDate = new Date(localFile.lastModifiedTime().toMillis());
isUpToDate = localDate.compareTo(remoteDate) > 0;
```

My coworker and I now have a disagreement about this code. He says that this might not work if the program is executed in a different time zone, and I say it will work because Java Date objects are not affected by time zones, only the instances of Calendar are. Am I right ? Is he right ?

Comment: Not what you asked, but I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the time zone affect a java.util.Date.compareTo() result?

No. The only thing compared by `Date` is the milliseconds since epoch.

This would be easy to write a test for: run the same code, setting the JVM's default time zone to different values.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, `java.util.Date` doesn't matter on the timezone, it is always a milliseconds-since-Unix-epoch value. If you want the time in a different timezone, then you need to do the following --

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();

        // Display the instant in three different time zones
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
        System.out.println(date);

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
        System.out.println(date);

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Riyadh"));
        System.out.println(date);

        // Prove that the instant hasn't changed...
        System.out.println(date.getTime());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

It’s not what you asked, but I thought it would be interesting to you and not least a lot of other people interested in this and similar questions. The doubt will probably go away if instead of the old-fashioned `Date` class you use `Instant` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
FTPFile remoteFile = ftpClient.mlistFile(remotePath);
Instant remoteInstant = remoteFile.getTimestamp().toInstant();
BasicFileAttributes localFile = Files.readAttributes(Paths.get(localPath), BasicFileAttributes.class);
Instant localInstant = localFile.lastModifiedTime().toInstant();
isUpToDate = ! localInstant.isBefore(remoteInstant);
```

(The code is not tested, please forgive any typo.) While `Date` sometimes pretends to be a date and time in a time zone (in particular its confusing `toString` method gives this impression), I can’t see any doubt that an `Instant` is just what the name says, a point in time, no more, no less. Absolutely independent of time zone.

In my comparison I have allowed the instants to be equal. I am using *not before* to mean *same time or after*. You can just use `isAfter()` if you require the local instant to be strictly after as in your own code.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.